# mod_rewrite based on last segment with any number of folders above

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, apache2

I am migrating an old site to a new one and need a large number of url redirects/rewrites.

As an example I need to redirect **/old_page** to **/new_page** the problem is that /old_page can have any number of url segments above it e.g. **/some/other/section/old_page**

Currently I have to use the following 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^old_page/?$ /new_page? [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/old_page/?$ /new_page? [R=permanent,L]
```

Is there anyway to achieve this with just one rule? I did try using this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?old_page/?$ /new_page? [R=permanent,L]
```

but this then results in unintended matches e.g. /do_not_move_old_page also gets redirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?old_page/?$ /new_page? [R=permanent,L]
```